# What's wrong in the ternary operator ? in java

Tags: java

below API return the boolean value as false ? but it should return the value True.what is the cause ?
 When put a debugging cursor point on the line ternary operator cannot able to find it. please guide the 
 way to debug this and solution too.

```
  public void isTrueOrFalse(){
            System.out.println("format for the new Date() core API = "+new Date() instanceof String);
            System.out.println("format for the new Date() core API = "+new Date());
            /*Date d=new Date(2016,11,20);*/
            /*Date d1=new Date(2016,11,20);*/
            /*System.out.println(d);*/

            DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date d1=new Date();
            Date todayWithoutTimeZone;
            try {
                todayWithoutTimeZone = formatter.parse(formatter.format(d1));
                System.out.println("something check="+todayWithoutTimeZone);
                System.out.println("condition check "+todayWithoutTimeZone.equals("Tue Nov 19 00:00:00 IST 2019"));
                boolean checkTest = todayWithoutTimeZone.equals("Tue Nov 19 00:00:00 IST 2019") ? true : false;


                logger.info("returned checked Status"+checkTest);


            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: `todayWithoutTimeZone.equals("Tue Nov 19 00:00:00 IST 2019")` already returns `true` or `false` and that's where your problem is: `Date.equals()` won't return true for `String` parameters (or anything other than a `Date` with the same timestamp).

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals-java.lang.Object-): *Compares* ***two dates*** *for equality. The result is true* ***if and only if the argument*** *is not null and* ***is a Date*** *object that represents the same point in time, to the millisecond, as this object.* Your parameter is a string, so the `equals` method will always return `false`.

Comment: Viewing your code can see a lot of compile issue.

Comment: @ShankarSaranSingh can you tell which are the lines getting errors?

Comment: @ram which IDE you are using for java development ?

Comment: @ShankarSaranSingh Eclipse bro

Comment: @ram do you see red error warnings in IDE ? thats called compile time errors, fix that first, and try to understand WHY that compile issue is coming.

Answer (score 4):

```
todayWithoutTimeZone.equals("Tue Nov 19 00:00:00 IST 2019")
```

`todayWithoutTimeZone` is a `Date`. It will never be equal to a `String`.

Comment: Thanks for notify this @Andy Turner in case it will be a new Date().equals(" some static data"); will work ?

Comment: @ram no, because `new Date()` is a `Date`, `" some static data"` is a `String`, and, to reiterate, a `Date` is never equal to a `String`.

Comment: then @Andy Turner  this is only possible solution ? new Date().equals(new Date);

Comment: System.out.println("format for the new Date() core API = "+new Date() instanceof String); it prints true  so what it mean ? it checks both are the objects i.e., String is a object and Date() as well object ?

Comment: @ram that's because operator precedence means that's equivalent to `System.out.println(("format for the new Date() core API = "+new Date()) instanceof String);`.

Comment: can you please clarify this ? instanceof will check for the type right ? here Date is type so it should return false right ?